# Integrating ngx-paypal into Angular 8 Webapp

Tags: angular

My app has a PayPal payment integration using [ngx-paypal](https://github.com/Enngage/ngx-paypal). I cannot get the PayPal buttons to render when I inject an html string from the `component.ts` into the `component.html`. The injection is for a popup payment window, which itself works fine, as shown. But, the inclusion of `ngx-paypal` into the injected string is ignored - no console errors. I have tried three variations, but none work - see the embedded comments. To prove that `ngx-paypal` is working, and not the problem, I include a **PROOF OF WORKING** directly in the component.html.

I have tried to include `ngx-paypal` directly in the `component.html`, as shown in **try4**, but it also doesn't work. **try4** is actually my preference, if we could get it working.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bob

**component.ts**

```
this.paymentText = 
`
 <div style="background-color: #d8e7f3">
   <p style="width: 350px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 15px; font-size: 16px;"><b>Please Select a Payment Method</b></p>
   <div style="display: flex;">
     <div style="width: 400px; padding-left: 15px;">
       <b>Payment Type:</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" id="inputPmtType" name="inputPmtType" disabled style="width: 70%; text-align: center; background-color: #eaffea;"> 
     </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div style="display: flex;">
     <div style="width: 400px; padding-left: 15px;">
       <b>Payment Amount:</b><input type="text" id="inputPmtAmt" name="inputPmtAmt" disabled style="width: 40%; text-align: center; background-color: #eaffea;"> &nbsp;$USD&nbsp;
     </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div style="display: flex;">
     <div  style="width: 90%; padding-left: 15px;">
       <b>Payment Method:</b>&nbsp;
       <div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 15px;">
         <input type="image" src="../../assets/img/TMD_Media/miota_logo381.png" id="miota-checkout-btn" style="width: 40px;" (click)="miotaBtnHandler()"/>
         <br>
         <br>
         <!--<div id="paypal-checkout-btn"></div>                         OLD WAY; WORKED-->
         <ngx-paypal [config]="payPalConfig"></ngx-paypal>         <!--   NEW WAY try1; NOT WORKING-->             
         <!--<ngx-paypal [config]="` +this.payPalConfig +`"></ngx-paypal> NEW WAY try2; NOT WORKING--> 
         <!--<ngx-paypal [config]=` +this.payPalConfig +`></ngx-paypal>   NEW WAY try3; NOT WORKING-->
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
`;
```

**component.html**

```
<span style="padding-left: 10px;">
  <button saJquiDialogLauncher="#payment-dialog"
      class="btn btn-default projectbtn myHide" [(ngModel)]="paymentDialogBtn"
      #namePD1 name="paymentDialogBtn" id="paymentDialogBtn" ngDefaultControl>
  </button>
</span>
<div id="payment-dialog" [saJquiDialog]="paymentDialogOptions" [innerHTML]="paymentText | safeurl: 'html'">
  <!--<ngx-paypal [config]="payPalConfig"></ngx-paypal>  NEW WAY try4; NOT WORKING-->
  <div class="hr hr-12 hr-double"></div>
</div>

<ngx-paypal [config]="payPalConfig"></ngx-paypal> <!--PROOF OF WORKING-->
```

**screenshot**

[image]

**saJquiDialog**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

$.widget("ui.dialog", $.extend({}, $.ui.dialog.prototype, {
  _title: function(title) {
    if (!this.options.title ) {
      title.html("&#160;");
    } else {
      title.html(this.options.title);
    }
  }
}));

@Directive({
  selector: '[saJquiDialog]'
})
export class JquiDialog implements OnInit {
  @Input() saJquiDialog: any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    $(this.el.nativeElement).dialog(this.saJquiDialog)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what `saJquiDialog` is, but it seems it's somehow interfering with the paypal component because the same code that's working outside of the `payment-dialog` div seems not to be working inside ... Does the ngx-paypal component create a dialog on it's own, like your screenshot suggests? Might be, one dialog inside the other won't work ...

Comment: No, ngx-paypal component does not create a dialog on its own. My screenshot shows all that ngx-paypal creates - the PayPal button, and the Debit or Credit Card Button. I think you're right about `saJquiDialog` interference, I just can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Ah, the dialog is the JquiDialog? Have you tried inspecting the DOM? Maybe the component is created but just not shown (erroneous size, position, ...)? It seems strange that there would be no error on the console if the component creation failed entirely ...

Comment: I added the code for the `saJquiDialog` directive. I don't see any problem with adding ngx-paypal within its div - do you?

Answer (score 0):

I determined that the `payPalConfig`, shown in `component.html`, was undefined, due to it being set in `component.ts`. I could not figure out how to pass the `payPalConfig` to the dialog directive, `saJquiDialog`, that I was using.

My solution was to use a simpler dialog, so I switched over to [Custom Modal](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-8-custom-modal), which is well described in the author's [blog](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/07/12/angular-8-custom-modal-window-dialog-box). In the modal's `open()` I placed a call to my `service.ts` that sets `payPalConfig`.

Thanks @derpirscher for your ideas.
Bob

**component.html**

```
      <span style="padding-left: 10px;">
          <button (click)="openModal('payment-details-1')"
              class="btn btn-default projectbtn myHide" [(ngModel)]="paymentDialogBtn"
              #namePD1 name="paymentDialogBtn" id="paymentDialogBtn" ngDefaultControl>
          </button>
      </span>

      <jw-modal id="payment-details-1">
          <h1>Payment Details</h1>
          <div id="payment-dialog" [innerHTML]="paymentText | safeurl: 'html'"></div>
          <ngx-paypal [config]="accountService.payPalConfig"></ngx-paypal>
          <button (click)="closeModal('payment-details-1');">Close</button>
      </jw-modal>
```